# Incorrect shared details returned from drive delta query

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-delta

I am trying to use Graph API to enumerate files that have been shared outside the organisation over time. Reading the docs, I think the best way of doing this is by identifying all sites/subsites and their corresponding drives, and then using the drive delta query to monitor for changes over time.

However, when calling delta on a drive ([DriveItem Delta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)) I get incorrect or incomplete results for OneDrive or SharePoint respectively with regards to sharing.

**OneDrive**: 
The delta query correctly returns when sharing on files is modified but seems to always return the scope as "users" (even if it is actually "organisation" or "anonymous"). Directly querying permissions on the item (via `/drives/<drive-id>/items/<item-id>/permissions`) shows the correct permission.

Am I misreading what the shared scope in the delta request is telling me here or is this a bug?

**SharePoint**: 
The delta query on SharePoint drives does not seem to reflect changes to sharing (i.e. the "shared" field is never included in a delta response)

Am I going about this the wrong way of does the API not expose this information?